# Spring security: Get access to current principal inside custom Filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Here my current `HttpFilterchain`:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final CorsConfigurationSource configurationSource = serverWebExchange -> {
            final var cc = new CorsConfiguration();
            cc.addAllowedOriginPattern(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            cc.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            cc.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);

            return cc;
        };

        // Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2Customizer = (config) -> config.opaqueToken();
        Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2Customizer = (config) -> config.jwt();

        return http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .cors().configurationSource(configurationSource).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/gicar/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Customizer)
            .addFilterAfter(new CommonsHeaderArePresentFilter(this.httpServletRequest), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
    }
```

Important lines are:

```java
.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Customizer)
            .addFilterAfter(new CommonsHeaderArePresentFilter(this.httpServletRequest), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
```

As you can guess, I've created a custom `Filter` `CommonsHeaderArePresentFilter` engaged to check if `user` request parameter match the custom claim "clientId" inside token.

So, in order to be able to get current token, I need to perform `CommonsHeaderArePresentFilter` after `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`.

`BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` code is:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CommonsHeaderArePresentFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String principal = this.httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        log.info(principal);

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Optional<String> userRequestParameter = Optional.ofNullable(req.getParameter("user"));

        if(userRequestParameter.isPresent()){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else{
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            String error = "Invalid API KEY";

            resp.reset();
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setContentLength(error .length());
            response.getWriter().write(error);
        }

    }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get current `Principal` from injected `httpServletRequest`:

```java
String principal = this.httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

I'm getting:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.security.Principal.getName()" because the return value of "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()" is null

However, it's `null`:

1. Why is it `null`?
2. How could I get access to authenticated user?

I've enabled websecurity debugging:

```
************************************************************

Request received for GET '/user?clientId=RDOCUI&clientSecret=dPZprxgxL07Vwgmi73MwR7uLDIioJxpp':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4806674b

servletPath:/user
pathInfo:null
headers:
host: localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept: */*
connection: keep-alive
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJzaElqX21OUnZQZUdod1V3ZDdHcUNadU0wNDJibHVjTW5XcTAyT0ZqNW5BIn0.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.ZuiPoV8vItl_XNpzci_8ftYYU-bfhZrr0uSUnSHUq0opfOKKspva9V9MdP_Vj6F50SHKt0WG0EV0dyZohcEsEBVjiPIK9pfrDHgr68hIpbGe1pQ51cCTsKwk2K6vS9WgNWuf3bvS81XAocOSLeQNap4GdiJ6XFjg6IOFalgPesXNvlJYgZ-db_JBe6poGOo2v6MB7MzIPPM9Ks8AqhpDQZPD_RevX03zQb6RNp8gZKwax9-Oqbwq6ptYhnP8ABEIjslb26USfqVcqrKf3DF7QL1BRtRwvwa-wwfrK5mUhmJMrubJon5yBOrNGYJfeqPUMjZ_S0KD6ay41yGgBSOqag
user-agent: HTTPie/3.2.1


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  CommonsHeaderArePresentFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************
```

As you can see, my filter is configuration after `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`.

Nevertheless, `principal` is `null`...

Comment: there is a bunch of things left out, have you setup a jwt proper nimbus validator?, have you tried accessing the principal in a controller? have you tried accessing `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` there is several things you can do

Comment: Can I get access to request parameters inside a validator or inside a ‘MappedJwtClaimSetConverter‘?

Comment: "1. Why is it null?" probably, because it is too early (who/which filter should have set it so far?) 2.How? ..it must be available...best via `SecurityContextHolder` ... (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html, ...)